# ARM/Bicep template for importing API Management operations

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I'm putting the final pieces together on deploying a bunch of APIs through API Management.

I have a number of App and Logic App backends that are combined in API Management.  Reverse engineering an ARM template from the portal suggests I have to write out each and every operation by hand to create the operations vi Bicep.

Is there a way, that like the portal, I can instruct ARM to use the OpenAPI specification generated automatically by the backend Apps and Logic Apps to automatically populate the operations?

Given the variety of operational paths, I feel like I'm going to be here all week typing them out as the variance is too much to have a loop.

Comment: Yes you can: see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/apis?tabs=json#apicreateorupdateproperties). Check the `format` property, it supports `openapi, swagger, etc...`

Comment: Have you come up with a solution ?

Comment: No, as with the above and the only answer, it all involves a lot of copying and pasting of schemas in.  AFAIK there is no way to to instruct ARM to go to the existing service and retrieve the definition as you would do with an import through the portal.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example on how I used OpenAPI for populating APIM Gateway. I passed the OpenAPI spec converted to single line into the Value field and set the format field to openapi+json. Here is an example

```
resource ImportedOpenapi 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis@2021-12-01-preview' = {
  parent: apimservicesymbolicname 
  name: 'ImportOpenApi'
  properties: {
    name: 'MyTestAPI'
    apiType: 'http'
    contact: {
      email: 'xyz@abc.com'
      name: 'test'
    }
    format: 'openapi+json'
    path: 'myapi'
    protocols: [
      'https'
    ]
    isCurrent: true
    subscriptionRequired: true
    type: 'http'
    value: '{"openapi":"3.0.1","info":{"title":"MyApi","contact":{},"version":"1.0"},"servers":[{"url":"https://xyz.api"}],"paths":...'
    }
  }
```